# SAX Parser and XAPI xml

Tags: java, saxparser

i want to parse a XAPI xml with the SAXParser.
But now i have a problem.

First a snippet of the xml:

```
<node id="24924135" lat="49.8800274" lon="8.6453740" version="12" timestamp="2012-05-25T15:13:47Z" changeset="11699394" uid="61927" user="AlexPleiner">
<tag k="addr:city" v="Darmstadt"/>
<tag k="addr:housenumber" v="41"/>
<tag k="addr:postcode" v="64293"/>
<tag k="addr:street" v="Kahlertstraße"/>
<tag k="amenity" v="pub"/>
<tag k="name" v="Kneipe 41"/>
<tag k="note" v="DaLUG Meeting (4st Friday of month 19:30)"/>
<tag k="smoking" v="no"/>
<tag k="website" v="http://www.kneipe41.de/"/>
<tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
```

And a snippet of my SAXParser code:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
  if (localName.equals("node")) {
    // Neue Person erzeugen
    poi = new POIS();

    poi.setLat(Float.parseFloat(atts.getValue("lat")));
    poi.setLon(Float.parseFloat(atts.getValue("lon")));
  }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {


  poi.setHouseNo(currentValue);


  if (localName.equals("addr:street")) {
    poi.setStreet(currentValue);
  }

  if (localName.equals("amenity")) {
    poi.setType(currentValue);
  }

}
```

The Latitude and Longtitude aren't the problem , but the Tag "tag".

How can i check for the "k" and get the Value of v ?

Anyone an idea? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you are interested in looking at are xml attributes, and will be represented in the `startElement(...)` method by the `Attributes` argument passed in.

What you need to do is very similar to what you have done for the `node` element.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
          Attributes atts) throws SAXException 
{
    //your other node code        

    if(localname.equals("tag")) {
        String k = atts.getValue("k");
        if(iAmInterestedInThisK(k)) {
            String v = atts.getValue("v");
            doSomethingWithThisV(v);
        }
    }
}
```